# Using a .Net 4.x WCF client assembly in .Net 6?

Tags: wcf, .net-core, .net-6.0

Our desktop app talks to a piece of software on a remote PC (which in turn controls an industrial device). Our app references a "client assembly" that was provided by the manufacturer, and is essentially an API exposing numerous methods, using WCF under the covers (over TCP). The target framework of this 3rd-party client assembly is .Net 4.5.

I'm in the process of migrating our desktop app to .Net6, and initially encountered the following exception on startup:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

This was fixed by adding the "System.ServiceModel.Primitives" NuGet package. (I had a similar exception for "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp", again fixed by adding that package).

I've run the portability analyzer (ApiPort) on the 3rd-party assembly, and every one of the messages relates to System.ServiceModel, e.g.:

```
"DefinedInAssemblyIdentity": "System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", 
"MemberDocId": "T:System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityOverTcp",
  "TypeDocId": null,
  "RecommendedChanges": "This part of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) won't be ported to .NET Core. See https://aka.ms/unsupported-netfx-api.",
  "SourceCompatibleChange": "",
  "TargetStatus": [
    null
  ]
```

With this in mind, and having added the earlier NuGet packages, how confident can I be that this assembly will work happily in our .Net 6 app? (It's going to be a while before I can actually test this area of the migrated app for real).

Comment: You can't use a .NET Framework library in .NET Core. `confident can I be` it won't.  You *can* compile the proxy project as a .NET Standard or .NET Core project though. If you have access to the WSDL document you can use CoreWCF to create a new proxy client from scratch

Comment: What is the *actual* communication protocol? SOAP? If so, you don't need any manufacturer library. In fact, you may be better of not using it. You can create a proxy in any language using the SOAP service's WSDL. If the protocol is NetTCP, things are more difficult. That was a proprietary protocol that fell out of fashion pretty quickly. Even printers use web services. You may be able to use CoreWCF's NetTcp support.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 support for WCF is less comprehensive, despite Microsoft's efforts. The mainstream option is [CoreWCF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/). There are still some issues, but some common features of WCF are supported.

There are other options, such as [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which has the advantage of being flexible and can be used across platforms and frameworks.